# Set the number of characters in particular row in datagridview?C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, set, rows

I know how to set the maximum number of characters in a particular column..

```
((DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[2]).MaxInputLength = 130;
```

But i don't know how to set the maximum number of characters in a certain row of that column..Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you will have to handle the `EditingControl showing` event and for your required Column/row you need to set the Length of the Editing TextBox control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are asking about is how to see maximum input length for `DataGridViewCell` and to accomplish that you have to attach grid to `EditingControlShowing` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   //check if currently selected cell is cell you want
   if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 2)
   {
       return;
   }

   if (e.Control is TextBox)
   {
       ((TextBox)e.Control).MaxLength = 130;
   }
}
```